Given a longer function, and a shorter function that are otherwise equivalent, why is the longer one more efficient?
This was a thought experiment I decided to follow through on, and I don't understand the results.  I'm sure it boils down to something simple, but I'm not really sure what I would even need to search.  Taking two functions, which used the same functions on the same dataset but in a different length of lines, would there be any noticeable difference in their efficiency?  I didn't think there would, or that at most it would be a slight difference in favor of the shorter function.  Apparently, I was wrong.
With these as the two functions:
def triplicate_1(nums):
    for i in nums:
        si = str(i)
        sum = 0
        for j in si:
            sum += int(j)
        if sum % 3 == 0:
            pass
        else:
            pass

def triplicate_2(nums):
    for i in nums:
        if sum([int(j) for j in str(i)]) % 3:
            pass
        pass

An arange from 1 - 10(11), and this timer:
print('Busy Method:',timeit.Timer('f(a)', 'from __main__ import a, triplicate_1 as f').timeit(1000000))
print('Clean Method:',timeit.Timer('f(a)', 'from __main__ import a, triplicate_2 as f').timeit(1000000))


The results came out to be:
Busy Method: 1.2368373669999073
Clean Method: 1.6709858689998782

I also ran it at every exponent of 10 up to 1000000.  The only area that the result was different was for 10000 trials where, for some reason, the Clean Method is consistently about 2/3s as long as the Busy Method.  None of this makes sense to me.  I'm sure I'm missing something basic, and I apologize for asking, but... what's going on here?

The most obvious difference is that the short version makes an explicit list of all the digits of j; the long version doesn't.

Why does it return pass when the conditional test fails? I suspect setup overheads vs cache size means that there is a sweet spot for explicitly forming the list in method 2. Method 1 just uses the numbers as they are generated.

The number of lines is unimportant; it's the cumulative effort needed to execute them. The cost of, for instance, using the variable si instead of iterating directly over the result of str(i) is negligible.

To answer in the order I see them, I actually later tracked it down to the use of sum vs iterating and adding.  Since all of the numbers used were single digit, sum operated slower than iterating through a single digit and adding it to zero.  Rewrote the code a couple of different ways to test it, and then tested sum itself vs an iteration function that did the same thing.  Sum is only really useful once you start working with about 1000 pieces of information.  Til then the difference is seemingly negligible (as long as it's greater than 1).

It returns pass because I wasn't looking to slow down testing by having it do anything extraneous.  It just needed to run the same calculations on both sides.  As mentioned above, I tracked the main issue down to my use of the sum function.  I am quite curious what you mean by setup overheads vs cache size, though, because that may explain the 10000 anomaly.

The data to conclude it is very small. Just by comparing 2 functions, we can't come to a conclusion.
Python one-liners are as efficient as multi-line loop functions and conditional statements.
It is very natural for one to doubt whether oneliners would take more time to execute. The reason for this doubt to occur is just because of the structure of one liners. whether it is a list made with for loop or multiple conditional statements, the order in which we write the oneliners is used to the reverse order of traditional multiline functions. In the traditional multiline function, the moment python finds out an if statement doesn't fulfil the condition, it can omit the respective entire block and can jump into the next else or elif block. But these all are only the perceptions and not the truth.
The reason is all the components of python language was written in c-language. They use different logics to understand different structure but to produce the same result(For two codes are considered equivalent in one-liner and traditional method respectively). So, there won't be any difference. In fact one-liners will be faster as it was introduced in later versions of python.

I appreciate the answer.  If I were interested in learning more about the C roots of python and how that affects efficiency as well as code interpretation, would there be a resource you might recommend?
